# How the inputs of string and double datatype should be taken in this program?

Tags: c++, pointers

I was learning about the concepts of pointers and just as I thought I got my concepts , this program caused me trouble understanding how the inputs of different datatype are being stored in a program..

And then I learnt about `cin.ignore()` and tested it out..

**Inputs**

```
32 // int
64.212 // float
4.76545 // double
* // char
Hey look at me! I know pointers! // string
```

**First Program without cin.ignore():**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int givenInt;
    float givenFloat;
    double givenDouble ;
    std::string givenString;
    char givenChar;

    cin>>givenInt;
    cin>>givenFloat;
    cin>>givenDouble;
    cin>>givenChar;
    getline(cin,givenString);

    cout<<"givenInt = "<<givenInt<<'\n';
    cout<<"address of givenInt = "<<&givenInt<<'\n';

    cout<<"givenFloat = "<<givenFloat<<'\n';
    cout<<"address of givenFloat = "<<&givenFloat<<'\n';

    cout<<"givenDouble = "<<givenDouble<<'\n';
    cout<<"address of givenDouble = "<<&givenDouble<<'\n';

    cout<<"givenChar = "<<givenChar<<'\n';
    cout<<"address of givenChar = "<<(void*)&givenChar<<'\n';

    cout<<"givenString = "<<givenString<<'\n';
    cout<<"address of givenString = "<<&givenString<<'\n';

    return 0;
}
```

**Output :**

```
givenInt = 32
address of givenInt = 0x7ffd62e17cd8
givenFloat = 64.212
address of givenFloat = 0x7ffd62e17cdc
givenChar = *
address of givenChar = 0x7ffd62e17cd7
givenString = 
address of givenString = 0x7ffd62e17ce0
givenDouble = 4.76545
address of givenDouble = 0x7ffd62e17ce8
```

Input string does not appear on output..

**First Program with cin.ignore():**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int givenInt;
    float givenFloat;
    double givenDouble ;
    std::string givenString;
    char givenChar;

    cin>>givenInt;
    cin>>givenFloat;
    cin>>givenDouble;
    cin.ignore();
    cin>>givenChar;
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,givenString);

    cout<<"givenInt = "<<givenInt<<'\n';
    cout<<"address of givenInt = "<<&givenInt<<'\n';

    cout<<"givenFloat = "<<givenFloat<<'\n';
    cout<<"address of givenFloat = "<<&givenFloat<<'\n';

    cout<<"givenDouble = "<<givenDouble<<'\n';
    cout<<"address of givenDouble = "<<&givenDouble<<'\n';

    cout<<"givenString = "<<givenString<<'\n';
    cout<<"address of givenString = "<<&givenString<<'\n';

    cout<<"givenChar = "<<givenChar<<'\n';
    cout<<"address of givenChar = "<<(void*)&givenChar<<'\n';

    return 0;
}
```

**Output :**

```
givenInt = 32
address of givenInt = 0x7ffcf69bd9a8
givenFloat = 64.212
address of givenFloat = 0x7ffcf69bd9ac
givenChar = *
address of givenChar = 0x7ffcf69bd9a7
givenString = Hey look at me! I know pointers!
address of givenString = 0x7ffcf69bd9b0
givenDouble = 4.76545
address of givenDouble = 0x7ffcf69bd9b8
```

Input Strings appear on the output..

**Second Program with cin.ignore():**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int givenInt;
    float givenFloat;
    double givenDouble ;
    std::string givenString;
    char givenChar;

    cin>>givenInt;
    cin>>givenFloat;
    cin>>givenDouble;
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,givenString);
    cin.ignore();
    cin>>givenChar;
    cin.ignore();

    cout<<"givenInt = "<<givenInt<<'\n';
    cout<<"address of givenInt = "<<&givenInt<<'\n';

    cout<<"givenFloat = "<<givenFloat<<'\n';
    cout<<"address of givenFloat = "<<&givenFloat<<'\n';

    cout<<"givenDouble = "<<givenDouble<<'\n';
    cout<<"address of givenDouble = "<<&givenDouble<<'\n';

    cout<<"givenString = "<<givenString<<'\n';
    cout<<"address of givenString = "<<&givenString<<'\n';

    cout<<"givenChar = "<<givenChar<<'\n';
    cout<<"address of givenChar = "<<(void*)&givenChar<<'\n';

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
givenInt = 32
address of givenInt = 0x7ffe1ed66698
givenFloat = 64.212
address of givenFloat = 0x7ffe1ed6669c
givenChar = e
address of givenChar = 0x7ffe1ed66697
givenString = *
address of givenString = 0x7ffe1ed666a0
givenDouble = 4.76545
address of givenDouble = 0x7ffe1ed666a8
```

Input character goes to the string variable and string's second letter gets printed on character variable..

I thought that since `double` uses buffer to store characters (If I am wrong, please correct me), let me use it at last since it does not affect the inputs which are taken after `double`. But I was wrong and it gave me similar kind of result as the first program.
And after testing out both programs with and without using cin.ignore(), I got to know that we need to use `cin.ignore()` whenever I take inputs of double and strings datatype.

My questions are,

1) Is my concept of "using cin.ignore() when taking inputs of double and string datatype" correct? Should I take the inputs in a particular order only?

2) Why is `(void*)` used along with `&givenChar` only for getting the address of a character type? `&givenChar` should do the job right?

Comment: This question has a really in-depth explanation for your first question [Why does std::getline skip input after a formatted extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: If you expect to read a line of input, this is what `std::getline` is for. No need to mess around with `ignore`, or anything like that. If the line of input is expected to be a numerical type, this is what `std::istringstream` is for. Take the resulting string, convert it to a `std::istringstream`, and use `>>` to parse it. But `>>` alone is not, I repeat, ***is not*** for reading a line of input, and all those contortions involving `ignore` is just a symptom of using the wrong tool for the wrong job.

Comment: So, if I take scanf instead of cin, scanf does a better job than cin, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you use `cin >> ...` the stream trims any and all whitespace from the beginning of the input and begins to parse the rest characters into the object. It stops when it finds whitespace or a newline. It won't skip the whitespace at the end but just leave it in the stream. `getline` does slightly the same except it *doesn't* trim whitespace at the beginning. It reads until it finds a newline, discards that newline, and stops. So if you have a `getline()` call after a `>>`, then you need to manually remove the extra whitespace at the beginning. That's what `ignore()` is for. It just skips a single character.
2. `&givenChar` has the type `char*`. The type of `std::cout`, `std::ostream`, has several overloads of the `<<` operator. One of them takes the type `char*` and treats it as a string. It attempts to iterate over the string until it finds a null terminator. In this case `&givenChar` is a pointer to a single character, not a pointer to the beginning of a character array. In order to select the correct overload a cast to `(void*)` is needed. The `<<` operator for `void*` displays the address.

Comment: So, after the double variable gets filled, there are white space remaining, so ```ignore()``` removes those whitespace in the stream and for the next variable, input gets stored properly, am I right?